# Like Websphere HA queue manager, is there any such WMQFTE cluster agent

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

In case of failover on one server, is there any concept in WMQFTE v8.0 as a failover MQFTE agent.

I have two linux servers in RHEL cluster, in case of failure on first one, how can i manage the MQFTE transfers with the second server with the same agent name.

Answer (score 0):

WMQFTE HA is strictly active/passive.  WMQFTE can not be deployed active/active.  You can not advertise the SYSTEM.FTE.* queues to an MQ cluster.  You can not balance the load of a transfer among multiple agents at the source or destination.

WMQFTE HA can be configured either with multi-instance queue managers, as described in this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1411_au/1411_au.html), or with HA software, as described in this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1101_bareham/1101_bareham.html).

Comment: I know this is very old post. Just want to highlight that IBM MQ MFT now supports out of the box Active/Standby High Availability. See here - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=transfer-highly-available-agents-in-managed-file